# Retrieving and exporting AD security group membership in PowerShell using input list

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Trying to create my first PS script ever to automate some of the repetitive work, and I have some limited success. I originally started with this:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity (Read-Host 'Enter group name') | Select samaccountname | Export-Csv -Path C:\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This prompts me for a security group name, I enter it, and it exports it to the file. Great! Now I want it to do the same thing, except having me type in a security group name and reperform this step a bajillion times, I want it to automatically pull the input from a file. Alas, we have..

```
foreach ($securitygroup in Get-Content -Path C:\input.txt)
{
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $securitygroup | Select samaccountname | Export-Csv -Path C:\test.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

I placed SG1 and SG2 on separate lines in input.txt and received the following errors:

```
Export-Csv : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is not valid. Change the value of the "name" argument and run the operation again.
At C:\test script.ps1:3 char:70
+ ... countname | Export-Csv -Path C:\test.csv -Appe ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-Csv], PSArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand

Get-ADGroupMember : An operations error occurred
At C:\test script.ps1:3 char:1
+ Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $securitygroup | Select samaccountname |  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (SG2:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8224,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

Looks like two different things going on here - the first error involves the argument "name"s value, and the second error because SG2 is somehow parsed incorrectly. Thoughts?

Comment: First of all I would recommend you to not store files in C:\ directory. you may encounter permissions problems. Create C:\temp\ folder instead.
Could you please show the output of `Get-Content -Path C:\input.txt` cmdlet.

I've also ran your code and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your exact code, and it worked. Maybe it's something either in your input file, or in one of the groups.

Try removing the Export-Csv part so it outputs to the command line, and see if the output is what you want:

```
foreach ($securitygroup in Get-Content -Path C:\input.txt)
{
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $securitygroup | Select samaccountname
}
```